# Possible to achieve inheritance from nested class definitions?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, scope

It surprises me that this code gives the subsequent error (Python 2.7.3):

```
class Foo(object):
    class Bar(object):
        pass
    class Baz(object):
        class InnerBar(Bar):
            pass
```

results in:

```
Enthought Python Distribution -- www.enthought.com
Version: 7.3-2 (64-bit)

Python 2.7.3 |EPD 7.3-2 (64-bit)| (default, Apr 11 2012, 17:52:16)
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-44)] on linux2
Type "credits", "demo" or "enthought" for more information.
Hello
>>> class Foo(object):
...     class Bar(object):
...         pass
...     class Baz(object):
...         class InnerBar(Bar):
...             pass
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in Foo
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in Baz
NameError: name 'Bar' is not defined
```

My suspicion is that this has to do with the particular execution of the equivalent `Bar = type(...)` `class` assignment, but even so, why doesn't `Bar` become available by closure within `Baz`?

Is there a way to workaround this for this precise kind of implementation (as in, I don't want to relax the constraint that `Bar` is a plain `class` defined inside of `Foo`, and that other classes within classes within `Foo` might want to inherit from `Bar`.

The particular use case that I have in mind is mimicking some database structures to make a more object oriented design that mirrors the schema in a data services project. Much of the code is autogenerated Python derived from a program that performs inspection on XSD, and so having classes defined within classes was a natural way to emulate certain things about XSD complex types, but with the added ability to also say when they are children of other complex types, etc. That's why I'm hesitant to pull a class outside of `Foo` for later inheritance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no closure here. The body of a class is **not** a parent scope when nested code is executed.

As far as code in nested scopes is concerned, only the global and the local scopes exist, the `Foo` class body is **not** a namespace that can be accessed.

See the [Naming and Binding documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding):

> If the definition occurs in a function block, the scope extends to any blocks contained within the defining one, unless a contained block introduces a different binding for the name. The scope of names defined in a class block **is limited to the class block**

Emphasis mine.

The work-around here is to use a nested function to produce a scope that *can* be accessed:

```
class Foo(object):
    def produce_nested_scope():
        class Bar(object):
            pass
        class Baz(object):
            class InnerBar(Bar):
                pass
        return Bar, Baz
    Bar, Baz = produce_nested_scope()
    del produce_nested_scope
```

Demo:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def produce_nested_scope():
...         class Bar(object):
...             pass
...         class Baz(object):
...             class InnerBar(Bar):
...                 pass
...         return Bar, Baz
...     Bar, Baz = produce_nested_scope()
...     del produce_nested_scope
... 
>>> Foo.Bar
<class '__main__.Bar'>
>>> Foo.Baz
<class '__main__.Baz'>
```

Comment: I'm still very unsure about why the documented process doesn't fully happen for `Bar` and `Baz` *within* the local namespace where the suite-execution is *in progress* for `Foo`. In whatever local namepsace is being developed for `Foo` before `Foo` is a bound name, within *that* namespace, why wouldn't all of `Bar`'s suite complete, then `Bar` is bound in *that* namespace, then all of `Baz`'s suite executes (including `InnerBar` which *can* look up one namespace level to find `Bar` since `Bar` would have been bound in *that* namespace), then `Foo` completes and is bound? What am I missing?

Comment: @EMS: Ah, I lack caffeine today. I thought you were using `Foo` inside `Foo`. I misread. No, class namespaces are **not** scopes for the purpose of looking up other names. `Bar` cannot be found because the `Foo` suite is not a parent scope.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a horrible hack:

```
class Foo(object):
    def hack(dest):
        class Bar(object):
            pass
        class Baz(object):
            class InnerBar(Bar):
                pass

        dest.update(locals())
    hack(locals())
```

```
>>> Foo.Bar
<class '__main__.Bar'>
>>> Foo.Baz.InnerBar
<class '__main__.InnerBar'>
```